# Scroll binding issue in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<div>` tag with id `page` after an ajax call the `div` tag is filled with 'n' number of `<li>` elements. When I scroll to the end of the div (`#page`) I need to add more `<li>` I can't do with following code. Can it be done with delegation?

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#page").bind("scroll",function(e){
            if($(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() < $(this).outerHeight())
            { 
               //End of scroll ;ajax data places here
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried delegate / live?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you do it with that code?  As I understand it, you want to bind to the scroll.  What I see that might be an issue is that you are binding [scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) on your div.  Is your div set with `overflow:scroll`?

If it is (or if you change your bound so that you use the window and do a different calculation), you should be able to do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#page").bind("scroll",function(e){
            if($(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() < $(this).outerHeight())
            { 
               $(this).append("<li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>");
            }
    });
});
```

Or if you are calling to get data from the server at that point:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#page").bind("scroll",function(e){
            if($(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() < $(this).outerHeight())
            { 
               $.ajax({
                   url: url
                   context: this, // used so that in success this is your div
                   dataType:html,
                   success: function(data) {
                      $(this).append(data);
                   }
               });
            }
    });
});
```

The key here is making sure you are binding scroll to an element it can be bound to.